# How to use syntax highlighting for .aspx & .ascx files in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, visual-studio, asp.net

When I open .aspx or .ascx files in notepad++, notepad++ open them as `Normal Text` files and so no syntax highlighting works. In the `Language` dropdown menu I dont see ASPX or ASCX options.

How to setup notepad++ so that it uses syntax highlighting when I open .aspx or .ascx files? I want to use the Visual Studio syntax highlighting in notepad++ for the .aspx and .ascx files. I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have the syntax highlight for you by adding `user extensions` on the ASP language inside the Style Configurator:

Settings > Style Configurator > Click "asp" > Where it has "User ext. :" on the bottom put "aspx ascx" without quotes then click Save & Close.

Select your language as ASP afterwards and this should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. ...probably the best answer provided you don't want to tackle defining your own. I did a quick search but didn't find a readily usable improved .aspx syntax highlighting - that isn't "VS Dark Theme".

Here is another reference that repeats what you have: 
Notepad ++ and the aspx extension: 
http://www.whatwasithinking.co.uk/2011/03/08/notepad-and-the-aspx-extension/